# How can i insert an image on html?

Tags: html

can you help me inserting an image on html page? I tryied to search on w3school but this doesn't work well.
I have to import a .jpg image format and apply a link on them

Comment: Please share , what have you tried ?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
<img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket"> 

<a href="url"><img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket"> </a>
```